# Marshal parameter in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class called Costumer which takes customer data as input and outputs a Complex type in XML format with many tags like Address, Post, Phone inside it.

In my main function i create a succesful implementation of one customer object called C1 and pass it as a marshall paramater and see the XML output as expected.

My question is what could be an efficient implementation if i want to add another customer C2. Obvioulsy i cannot create an ArrayList .Since marshall parameter does not take ArrayList as a parameter.

Thank YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to produce XML with a list of customer elements? You'll need another type to represent your list and the you'll need to annotate that type too. Then construct an instance of the "list type" and marshall that.

Comment: Why don't you want to do it that way? I don't think there's another one, other than maybe using xml schema and generating classes from it.